# Qt app finds libraries when launched from QtCreator, but not from command line

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, qt-creator

I need to ship a product with shared libraries (Ubuntu) in a folder I've created ('shared') within the project directory--i.e., shared libraries that are *not* in `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`, etc. To this end I've done this in the `.pro` file, i.e.

```
LIBS += -Lshared/gsl -lgsl -lgsl_cblas
```

NB the executable is in the same directory asy the 'shared' folder.  Everything works when I launch the program in debug mode from QtCreator.  In addition the program fails to launch if I remove or rename the libs in 'shared', and also I've verified that the app is not finding these libraries anywhere else.   But when I launch from the command line, I get

> error while loading shared libraries: libgslcblas.so.0: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

What's going on?

**EDIT**: The solution is a variation on lionbest's below, as developed in the comments.  For some reason, it turns out that on my platform `qmake`/`QMAKE_FLAGS` only allows a specific format for linker options, and not the one you find googling around for other instances where people have worked with `QMAKE_FLAGS`.  Namely,

```
QMAKE_FLAGS += "-Wl,-rpath,\'\$$ORIGIN/shared/gsl\'"
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH=
```

Specifically, the problem was that the parser (or linker) would not accept `-rpath=...`, despite the fact that this seems to work for everyone else.  Ubuntu 12.04, gcc 4.6.3, Qt 4.8.0, QtCreator 2.4.1 "based on Qt 4.7.4".  Hope this experience can save someone else the same frustration.

Comment: Qtcreator uses its own environment when launching apps, I think you should check it.

Comment: @Lol4t0 Thanks, looking into this..

Comment: @Lol4t0 lionbest's answer and my comment shows where things are at right now.

Comment: @MattPhillips, I want to be clear about your answer.  (This problem still occurs with Qt 5.9.8.)  The two lines you give in your "EDIT" replace the "LIBS +=" line?  Or are in addition to it?  And the "QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH=" line is really supposed to not have anything on the assignment side?  This all seems like black magic... can you explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start a program with environmental variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=shared/gsl` or add a RPATH to linker settings:

```
LIBS += -Wl,-rpath=shared/gsl
```

If you want to make shortcut for your application, most distribution (based on Gnome, KDE, LXDE and XFCE) use a .desktop file. QtCreator probably generated one for you. You need to edit it or generate it, and put to $HOME/.local/applications or /usr/share/applications/ during installation. In desktop file you could add envirometal varible and starting directory as follow:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/<path_to_libs>/ /<path>/app -extra_options
```

If you need to run your application in specific directory add line:

```
Path=/<path_to_your_application_working_dir>
```

You can use ${} inside path.

Comment: Doing `$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=shared/gsl` indeed works, thanks--but I can't expect the user to do this (also it doesn't seem to work when the user double-clicks the icon, which I also want)--so I need to do this within the `.pro` file or Project settings page I take it.  Unfortunately the second solution doesn't work for me, are there any variations I should also try?

Comment: If you edit the `.pro` file with a text editor, you should be able to add the RPATH. I can't seem to find an RPATH setting in the GUI...I'm surprised it doesn't have one.

Comment: I'm not sure if I correct type it, i will check that. `user double-clicks the icon` you mean .desktop file?

Comment: @lionbest I mean from a window, there is an icon associated with the executable (as with any program).  In most cases this is what the user clicks on to launch an application--just the standard executable icon, that's all.

Comment: @TravisGockel I've edited `QMAKE_LFLAGS` and `QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH` with different versions of lionbest's second answer, but I still can't make it work.  How is changing it with a text editor different from doing it within QtCreator?

Comment: I make a typo. QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH don't need `-Wl,-rpath=` prefix. Also try specify full path to library. And find out that the lass call to g++ is with `-Wl,-rpath=` .

Comment: @lionbest I can't get anything to work.`QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH=<my path>` concatenates the path I supply with the Qt library path to produce a nonsensical nonexistent directory.  `LIBS += -Wl, -rpath=shared/gsl`  as well as the same with `QMAKE_LFLAGS` gives me an "unrecognized option" error, and so do all simple syntactic variations of this I've tried.

Comment: `LIBS += -Wl,-rpath=shared/gsl` <= no space

Comment: @lionbest This gives me "unrecognized option: '-rpath=shared/gsl'" ! I'm using g++ 4.6.3, linker = ld, on Ubuntu 12.04 (fresh install) if that helps.

Comment: That's strange, I do test it with 12.04 and system qmake (/usr/bin/qmake-qt4) either. QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH do not work in my case. Maybe try add a quotes, so in my case I used `QMAKE_LFLAGS += "-Wl,-rpath=.libs"` and it works fine.

Comment: @lionbest I put the quotes on, used exactly your code as well as `-rpath=shared/gsl`, and got the same error.  Also the problem with modifying the `.desktop` file is that I don't want the user to have to install anything--I'd like it to work right out of the directory, without having to make changes anywhere else in the system.  I have to go now but if you have any other ideas please write them and I'll try them tomorrow.